# Warning in Asynctask usage

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use asynctask in one of my android application like below but its giving me warning like this
**Unchecked Call to 'execute(Params…)' as a member of raw type 'android.os.AsyncTask'**

```html
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONArray products = null;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    Methods methods;
    AppItem appItem;
    LanguageItem languageItem;
    RoundedImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        imageView = (RoundedImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.splashscreen)
                .fit().centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);

        methods = new Methods(this);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AsyncServerOnlineCheck().execute();
            }
        },1000);
    }

    public class AsyncServerOnlineCheck extends AsyncTask {
        boolean isReachable;

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            isReachable = NetworkCheck.isReachable(Splash.this);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            if (isReachable) {
                new loadAppData().execute();
                //Toast.makeText(SplashsActivity.this, "Server is online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
    connectionerror();
            }
        }
    }


    public void connectionerror() {
       // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection Error!");

        alertDialog.setMessage("There Some issue to connect Server...Please try again later");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Retry",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        new AsyncServerOnlineCheck().execute();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Exit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Splash.this.finish();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

I learning android yet and confused in this warning. I am not able to solve the puzzle. Let me know if someone can correct me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to use asynctask in one of my android application like
>   below but its giving me warning like this Unchecked Call to
>   'execute(Params…)' as a member of raw type 'android.os.AsyncTask'

The warning is caused by the params for the `AsyncTask`.

**change your class definition**:

```
public class AsyncServerOnlineCheck extends AsyncTask {

}
```

**to this**:

```
public class AsyncServerOnlineCheck extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object>{

}
```

[**From Android Developers:**](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

`Params`, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.

`Progress`, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.

`Result`, the type of the result of the background computation.

Further reading - [**AsyncTask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: If I use like that than its giving error like ' class AsyncServerOnlineCheck ' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method do in background....'

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you define your async task, you aren't defining the generics that it should be using.  Hence there's no checks on the types of variables passed around, which means if you have a bug you'll crash at runtime rather than fail to compile, which is generally worse.  Define the 3 generic types like `public class AsyncServerOnlineCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`  or whatever is applicable to get rid of the warning.